# preg_replace_callback, removing apostrophes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have the following regular expression callback, and the issue that I am having, is that in the final result, the `'` are removed. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

```
<?php
$eval = "'$server.REQUEST_URI' == '/user/photos'";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\'(.+)\'/isU', function($matches){
    $match = $matches[1];
    $find = Object69::find($match);
    return !empty($find) ? $find : $match;
}, $eval);

var_dump($result);
```

here is the result of `$result`

```
string(29) " /user/photos == /user/photos"
```

This is what I was expecting:

```
string(29) "'/user/photos' == '/user/photos'"
```

and here are the arrays that it finds `$matches`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "'$server.REQUEST_URI'"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "$server.REQUEST_URI"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "'/user/photos'"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "/user/photos"
}
```

Comment: What does `Object69::find(` do? Maybe put the quotes in the capture group?

Comment: `Object69::find()`, searches the `$_SERVER` array for for the value after the `.` and returns it. If the value is not found an empty value is returned `''` or `null`.

Comment: Why not do it all in the regex?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `$match` doesn't have quotes, so you could use this return instead: `return !empty($find) ? $find : $matches[0];`. `$matches[0]` will contain the result with quotes.

Comment: @HamZa That half way works, it only works on the second item in the string, the first item is quoteless.

Comment: doing it this way: `return !empty($find) ? "'$find'" : $matches[0];` does work, but I don't like the idea of manually adding the quotes...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn  I think the mystery is around your strange `Object69::find()`. You will need to choose where to add those quotes: in the `find()` method or in the return statement. Another way is to add some magic into your regex: `"/(?<=').+?(?=')/s"` and use `$match = $matches[0];`

Comment: @HamZa that regex worked just how I wanted!